# java not seeing connected device COM4

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino

java is not seeing the arudino on COM4 the code seems to be working

```
package tester;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
        "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                    "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
        "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
        "COM4", // Windows
};
/**
* A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
* converting the bytes into characters 
* making the displayed results codepage independent
*/
private BufferedReader input;
/** The output stream to the port */
private OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
            // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
            // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was       suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
            System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port.
 * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            String inputLine=input.readLine();
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
    main.initialize();
    Thread t=new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
            //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
            try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        }
    };
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Started");
}}
```

seems to be working but all i get in console is

```
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Could not find COM port.
Started
```

i looked in to the jar version being off but rxtx asked for it in there stable release

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assuming that it will be always "COM4" on windows ? Maybe try to get the com port like this (from http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier):

```
public static List<String> getSerialPorts(){
  List<String> vp=new ArrayList<String>();
  Enumeration portList=CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
  while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
    CommPortIdentifier portId=(CommPortIdentifier)portList.nextElement();
    if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
      vp.add(portId.getName());
    }
  }
  return vp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to RxTx and the (deprecated) Java Communications API I had luck with [jSerialComm](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/)

I made a dialog box with a drop down choice of 127 com ports (without the reserved) as the first thing to let the app know which COM port is in use. Then used it in the constructor for the next new class instance.